# how to change dynamically select option list on the basis of previous selection in django without page loading

Tags: django

I have three field State -> District -> Places. Data should appear in this sequence. Like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUNHA.jpg) Image.

How can i achieve this in django. Data should comes from default db.

I did it in php. Here is the code

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#selstates").change(function(){
      if($("#selstates").val()){
          $.ajax({
               url: '../helper/fetch_district.php',
               type: "POST",
               data: {tempstate: $("#selstates").val()},
               cache: false,
               dataType:"text",
               success:function(response)
                {
                    $("#seldis").html(response);
                }
              });
          }
      else{
              $('#seldis').html('<option value="">Select State first</option>');
         }
    });
   });
```

fetch_district.php file:

```
<?php
    include '../config/db/dbconfig.php';
    if(isset($_POST["tempstate"]) && !empty($_POST["tempstate"])){  
        $temp = $_POST['tempstate'];
        $sql= "select * from districts where state_id='$temp'";
        $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if($res->num_rows > 0){
            echo '<option value="">Please Select</option>';
            while($row =mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
                 echo "<option value='".$row['district_id']."'>" . $row["district_name"] . "</option>" ;
                }
        }
        else {
            echo '<option value="-1">Not available</option>';
        }
}
?>
```

But here in django i cant understand how can i code it. Please help me

Comment: onchange StateSeclectBox   call getDistrictFunction which do a ajax call to get DiSTRICTS from database for given state, same can be done for getting places

Comment: i did it in php ....i attached the php code....but i cant understand in django...please help me....i am learning django

Answer (score 1):

This is basically translation of existing code.

Meanwhile,

#### Register a URL for returning the list of district.

```
url(r'^/districts/$', views.districts, name='districts'),
```

#### Write a view function to return `JSONResponse` of districts

```
# views.py
def districts(request):
     state = request.GET.get('state')
     districts = District.objects.filter(state=state)
     return JSONResponse(districts)
```

#### Put your JS into your Django template and update it to make a request to the registered URL.

```
... 
$.ajax({
    url: '/districts',
    type: "GET",
    data: {state: $("#selstates").val()},
    cache: false,
...
```